# Hirose connector footprint comprehension

Tags: footprint, cad

I am trying to understand how the [datasheet](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?documentid=D31649_en) of the DF40 series of connector from Hirose describe the footprint.

There is a part of the footprint receptacle that is hatched and I don't understand exactly what it means.

[image: Footprint]

[image: Footprint note]

Does it mean that the hatched area is part of the pad (copper), but covered by soldermask?
But in that case, why cover a part of the pad by soldermask? could it be possible to only have the pad the size of the non-hatched area?

Comment: That sounds correct. Might be so the pad does not lift/peel (it is a connector after all) but there's no reason to have solder there since it could lift the connector and you can't get to it with an iron anyways